# Fresh install of Debian 7.8.0, cant apt-get install build-essential

Tags: debian, apt

Fresh install of debian-7.8.0-amd64 into a virtual machine.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

gives me these errors:

```
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcairo2 : Breaks: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (< 2.4.5-2~) but 1.8.1-3.4 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: glib-networking (< 2.33.12) but 2.32.3-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What gives?

Comment: Looks like you added `jessie` or `sid` to your `sources.list` on a `wheezy` system. You can't mix suites.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before installing?